# The wikipedia argument that the symmetric normalized Laplacian has non-negative eigenvalues

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to understand an equality in the Symmetric Normalized Laplacian section of the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Symmetric_normalized_Laplacian).

The Symmetric Normalized Laplacian is defined for a simple graph $G$ is defined as
$L^{sym}:= D^{-\frac{1}{2}} L  D^{-\frac{1}{2}} = I - D^{-\frac{1}{2}} A D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ where $L$ is the Laplacian of the graph ($L=D-A$ for $D$ the degree matrix, and $A$ the adjacency matrix).

In this section, a goal is to show that the eigenvalues of $L^{sym}$ are non-negative and real. Since $L^{sym}$ is symmetric, then by the spectral theorem for Hermitian matrices, the eigenvalues are real. To show they are non-negative, the author considers an eigenvector $g$ of $L^{sym}$ with  eigenvalue $\lambda$, and suppose that $D^{\frac{1}{2}}f = g$, where $f,g$ are $n$ dimensional real valued vectors that the author considers functions on the vertices of the graph (a graph with $n$ vertices) and in the preceding notation $f(i), g(i)$ is the $i$'th component of $f,g$ respectively.

A series of equalities shows the desired result using a Rayleigh Quotient for the left-hand side:

$$\lambda = \frac{\langle g, L^{sym} g \rangle}{\langle g, g \rangle} = \frac{\langle g, D^{\frac{-1}{2}} L D^{\frac{-1}{2}}g \rangle}{\langle g, g \rangle} = \frac{\langle f, Lf \rangle}{\langle D^{\frac{1}{2}} f, D^{\frac{1}{2}} f \rangle} = \frac{\sum_{u \sim v} (f(u) - f(v))^2}{\sum_v{f(v)^2 d_v}} \geq 0$$ where $u \sim v$ are the unordered pairs of adjacent vertices $\{u, v\}$ and $d_v$ is the degree of vertex $v$.

I am not sure why $\langle f, Lf \rangle = \sum_{u \sim v} (f(u) - f(v))^2$.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ the vertices of graph $G$,
$d_i$ the degree of vertex $i$,
$f_i=f(i)$ for brevity.

On the one hand
$$
\langle f,Lf\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n d_if_i^2-2\sum_{i\sim j}f_if_j.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\sum_{i\sim j}(f_i-f_j)^2
=\sum_{i\sim j}(f_i^2+f_j^2)-2\sum_{i\sim j}f_if_j
=\sum_{i=1}^n d_if_i^2-2\sum_{i\sim j}f_if_j.
$$